# Access MS SQL server from CentOS (OpenOffice calc)

Tags: odbc, centos-6, ms-sql, openoffice-base

I installed FreeTDS in CentOS 6 and I can connect from php to remote MS SQL server. However I cannot set up odbc connection so that it shows in list of ODBC connections in OpenOffice apps.

If my server is called [10.0.0.11\myinstance] in freetds.conf what should I put in odbcinst.ini, and what in odbc.ini in order to be able to see this connection availabe for use in OpenOffice Base and Calc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In odbcinst.ini add

   ```
   [FREETDS]
   Description     = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
   Driver          = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
   ```
2. In ~/.odbc.ini add:

   ```
   [MSSQLTestServer]
   Driver  = FreeTDS
   Description     = MSSQL DB
   Trace   = No
   Server      = 10.0.0.11\myinstance
   Database        = MyDataBaseName
   ```

Now I have MSSQLTestServer listed as an available source and can use it in OO.